# Selectable - get inner selected items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get a selected item, when selecting is used on an element.
Here's the html code:

```
<div id="yearCal" class="ui-selectable">
    <div id="month_1" class="month">
        <div class="monthTitle">January</div>
        <div class="monthDays" id="month_1_days">
            <div class="monthDay ui-selectee" id="1-1">1</div>
            <div class="monthDay ui-selectee" id="1-2">2</div>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And that's the jQuery code:

```
$( "#yearCal" ).selectable({ filter: "div.monthDay" });
$( "#yearCal" ).on( "selectableselecting", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log($("div#yearCal.monthDay ui-selectee ui-selected"));
} );
```

How can I get the selected items if I'm selecting elements of the `yearCal`?
What I'm, tying to do is, that if I select the 1st of January and then selecting the 1st of February, I want all days/div items inbetween these two days to be selected. Therefore I want the ids of the selected items. How do I get the selected items?

Comment: Probable dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861589/jquery-selectable-how-to-make-items-selected-at-1st-load

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected inner items using `ui.selecting.id` inside the function `selectableselecting` and `selectableunselecting`.

Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selecting and http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-unselecting

In this snippet I'm logging the selected element and setting a specific class, but you can do all you stuff:

```
$("#yearCal").on("selectableselecting", function (event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.selecting.id);
    $('#' + ui.selecting.id).addClass('boxed');
});

$("#yearCal").on("selectableunselecting", function (event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.unselecting.id);
    $('#' + ui.unselecting.id).removeClass('boxed');
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/shTpK/