# Select list items on page load with JQuery UI Selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

I am trying to set up a list of of items that are selectable -and would like to have some of the list items already selected when the page loads.  The user needs to be able to select multiple items (got this part working) but needs to be able to unselect the preselected items in the list ...as if the user had originally clicked on them to select them.  Thanks for any advice you can give-

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e) {       //acts as if the control key is pressed so that more than one item can be selected
    e.metaKey = true;
    }).selectable();
});
```

**Style:**

```
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
#selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 10%; overflow:auto;}
#selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<ol id="selectable" >
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU12AM">12:00AM</li>     
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU125AM">12:30</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU1AM">1:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU15AM">1:30</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU2AM">2:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU25AM">2:30</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU3AM">3:00</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: How are you preselecting? What is the criteria for that?

Comment: My plan is to pass the data in from the last time they visited the page with a list of the values that were selected.  So after these are selected, the values are posted with ajax to save them for the next page visit.  (I didn't include the posting part because that is working okay.)

Comment: Found the answer in this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861589/jquery-selectable-how-to-make-items-selected-at-1st-load

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script>
jQuery(function() {
    $(".ui-widget-content").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
    var element = $(e.target);
    if (element.hasClass('selected')) {
        element.removeClass( "selected" );
    }
    else{
    element.addClass( "selected" );
    }
    });
});


</script>
<style>
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
#selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 10%; overflow:auto;}
#selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
.selected { background: #0014FF; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ol id="selectable" >
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU12AM">12:00AM</li>     
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU125AM">12:30</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU1AM">1:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU15AM">1:30</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU2AM">2:00</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU25AM">2:30</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content" value="SU3AM">3:00</li>
</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

try this code, i hope its help

Comment: Thanks Michal - how do I set which list item would be pre-selected on the load by your code?  (Sorry, I am a noobie)